# av_guess_format return null

Tags: api, null, ffmpeg

I used example from  http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/output-example_8c-source.html :

```
out_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
out_ctx->oformat = av_guess_format(NULL, filename, NULL);
if (out_ctx->oformat == NULL)
{
    out_ctx->oformat = av_guess_format("mpeg4", NULL, NULL);
    if (out_ctx->oformat == NULL)
    {
        LOGI(1, "Could not guess output format\n");
        exit(1);
     }
}
```

av_guess_format always return null. I don't understand what I must re-configured in FFMPEG for enable any formats.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to identify? What is the extension and what does the 'file' utility return when run against the file?

Comment: This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526738/ffmpeg-av-guess-format-returns-null

Answer (score 3):

If you read the thread, you will see that the question hasn't been answered - there is even another poster asking for the final solution, but no response from the original asker. I am also having a hard time with this, and as such feel that this thread needs to be left open since the original question remains unanswered.

But, since I now know the answer, I might as well share it here:

You must call av_register_all() as well as avcodec_register_all() after you have set up the codec library with a call to avcodec_init(), this solved the issue for me and is working nicely now. Please let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();
```

before using `av_guess_format()` solved the problem for me.